# "Unknown error when attempting to lock file."

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-enterprise

I have user when he opens a document from a document library, the document opens in Microsoft Word 2007, when clicks on the 'Edit Document' button he gets the error message "Unknown error when attempting to lock file.".

This issue happens frequrently and on the same file another coworker cna open the same file and click the 'Edit Document' button and no error message appear.

Current environment: SharePoint 2010
It's a normal document library, it's an OOTB document library.

Help please.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds very much like this issue answered on MSDN http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/9fc23a2d-5811-4cd4-b7d5-319528866ce4

The actual change needed to be performed is actually explained here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/870853